# Angular ContentChildren get directive Inputs and TemplateRef Across Modules

Tags: angular

I'm trying access the content children of a component when it is used in a different module, but the content children variable I declare is always empty.

I'm writing a component that I can use anywhere in my app. The component should have access to ng-templates inside it's tags. It will use the inputs on these templates to create a custom datagrid or table.

I can get this to work when it's all in the same module, but for some reason when it's in its own module it stops working.

See this StackBlitz for a code sample

https://angular-tfohdd.stackblitz.io

**Edit:** Someone asked for code even though I provided a stackblitz sample, so here it is in the question for your convenience.

The app component is using the parent component and declaring an ng-template inside of the components tags. I'm trying to get a template reference to the ng-template using a directive with an attribute selector. If My Parent was inside of the app module this code would work, but since it's inside the test module, it's not working.

**app.component.html:** this is inside the app module

```
<my-parent>
    <ng-template myDirective myDirective2 title="Title1">
        <div></div>
    </ng-template>
</my-parent>
```

**parent.component.ts:** this is inside the test module

```
import { Component, Input, Directive, ContentChildren, AfterContentInit, QueryList, TemplateRef, VERSION } from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective  {
  @Input() title: string;

  constructor(public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) {}
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html'
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterContentInit  {
  @ContentChildren(MyDirective) details: QueryList<MyDirective>;  

  ngAfterContentInit(){
    console.log(this.details);
  }
}
```

**parent.component.html:** this is inside the test module

```
Work:
<div *ngFor="let detail of details"> 
  <div>title: {{detail.title}}</div>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="detail.templateRef">
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

**test.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ParentComponent, MyDirective } from './parent.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [ParentComponent, MyDirective],
  exports: [ParentComponent]
})
export class TestModuleModule { }
```

Comment: Please show us some code, but If I understand you correctly, then I'm afraid you will have to create service for that which would hold reference. it's because (I assumed that you use `@ViewChild` or `@ContentChild`) `ContentChild` look up for  tags inside component and lower in structure

Comment: @PatrykBrejdak Hi Patrick, I provided a stackblitz in the original post, but I have edited the question to also include the code inside of itself. Please, let me know if you need more info to help me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by exporting the directive in the test module:

**test.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ParentComponent, MyDirective } from './parent.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [ParentComponent, MyDirective],
  exports: [ParentComponent, MyDirective ]
})
export class TestModuleModule { }
```

Comment: can you explain why you have used "myDirective2" in the below code.   <ng-template myDirective myDirective2 title="Title1">.   Is it some other directive you are using which is irrelevant to the question? Actually, I am trying to resolve the similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it saved me quite some trouble.